# How to return a lost iPhone 8?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, find-my-iphone

We found a new iPhone 8 in a foreigner country, the owner of the phone is also a tourist in that country.
The sim card in this phone is a new local sim card that this owner bought at that same day( I know by an sms on the lock screen he received about it).

It’s locked with touch ID.

We really really wanted to find this man, but we couldn’t.

1. We waited for him to call but we suspect that he doesn’t know his own phone number because it’s a new number he bought probably for data only.
2. He didn’t use Find my iPhone(i think) or got any message from a friend on the lock screen( because this sim is a new number/data only probably)

Now, i am not sure i can find him or return it to him because we left that city, and soon the country anyway.

I left with a locked new iPhone 8 that i feel guilty to use anyway.

What are my options to give it back?
I feel bad to ask - but if I can’t find him- can i use this device? Unlock it and remove all data?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the service provider to see if they can pull data on the SIM and contact him?

Comment: This wasn't very well thought through... Someone lost a phone.  The best thing to have done would be to leave it where you found it, or if on the floor lifted to some prominent location. This way, when the owner realised they'd lost it they could retrace their steps to find it. Instead you removed it from where it could be found & then left the city. Even if you removed it, you should have handed it to someone in authority - depending on location, at least the owner of the establishment, or the police. You have now effectively stolen it, even if that was not your intent.

Comment: ...& you now own a brick. No-one but the original owner, or Apple, can unlock it. Your last remaining hope is they have find my iPhone enabled & can message it when they get to a computer. Keep it charged, switched on & in reach of either a phone signal or WiFi.